# dataTables fnFilter column on img filename

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I'm trying to filter a column, based on the image file name in the src attribute of the  tag.

My row looks like this:

```
<tr class="unread odd">
    <td class=" "><input type="checkbox" name="r28416" value="1"></td>
    <td class=" "><img src="img/icons/bullet_yellow.png" alt="A" title="A"></td>
    <td class="nw ">Non-Lu</td>
    <td class=" "><a class="fancybox" href="tpl/laboratoires/details.php?id=28416">J9121702</a></td>
    <td class=" ">Data</td>
    <td class=" ">378192</td>
    <td class=" ">John Doe</td>
    <td class=" ">DOEJ54161235</td>
    <td class="nw  sorting_1">2012-07-12 12:02</td>
    <td class=" ">0</td>
    <td class=" ">40</td>
```

I'm using this line as the filter:

```
table.fnFilter( "bullet_yellow", 1 );
```

Every other colum works, and I have different filters for other column. Just doesn't work with this one. ANy thoughts?

Comment: That sort of functionality is not built in to DataTables. You'd have to use a custom filtering plugin.

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked when I just added the text to filter for in a `span` with `display:none`.

```
 <td class=" ">
  <img src="img/icons/bullet_yellow.png" alt="A" title="A">
  <span style="display:none;">bullet_yellow</span>`
 </td>
```

Comment: Nice, simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to put the src into a hidden column and then use that column to sort/filter on.  I had to sort on a different column becuase my second column was converted to images.

```
aoColumns: [
{"sType": "html", "bSortable": true},
{"iDataSort": 2, "bSortable": true, "bUseRendered":false},
{"bVisible": true, "sType": "numeric"}
]
```